# How can I find the amount of free disk space only using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, disk-space-utilization

I have a SQL (2005) server for which I need to monitor the amount of free disk space.  It is not currently running a web server so a normal ASP/.Net monitor page won't work in this case.  Is there any way that I can find the amount of free disk space on the server using only a SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `EXEC xp_fixeddrives` ?

A decent list of stored procedures which aren't well documented [here](http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/Undoc/UndocExtSP.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty good tip here (if you allow extended stored procedures)

[Determine Free Disk Space in SQL Server 2000/2005](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1706)